# ionic build error: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0

Tags: android, ssl, gradle, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to build an ionic android app. I am following this tutorial [Cordova and Ionic | Android HTML5 App Development Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qVOwGyQB3DQ)
to create my first ionic app. Although the operating system that I have in linux mint 17.3.

Everything is working except for the last command i.e. sudo ionic build android. I am getting following error log:

```
abc@abc-PC14 ~/workspace/public_html/ionic/hellowWorld $ sudo ionic build android

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Running command: /home/scoders/workspace/public_html/ionic/hellowWorld/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/scoders/workspace/public_html/ionic/hellowWorld
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=/home/scoders/android-sdk-linux
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
         > hostname in certificate didn't match: <repo1.maven.org> != <199.27.79.209>

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.364 secs
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/scoders/workspace/public_html/ionic/hellowWorld/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/scoders/workspace/public_html/ionic/hellowWorld/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

First i assumed that it might be SSL gradle error and tried to fix using [gradle-trust-all](https://github.com/arteme/gradle-trust-all)

But it is still giving the same error.

How to resolve this error..?

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering this issue as cordova in their [latest release](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/05/24/tools-release.html) added Telemetry to collect data for data driven development for some analytics

Error response:

- A timed prompt asking the user to opt-in or out is displayed the
  first time cordova is run. It lasts for 30 seconds, after which the
  user is automatically opted-out if he doesn't provide any answer.
- In
  CI environments, the `CI` environment variable can be set, which will
  prevent the prompt from showing up.
- Telemetry collection can also be
  turned off on a single command by using the `--no-telemetry-flag`.

## Commands to resolve or disable this, using CLI

- cordova/ionic telemetry on
- cordova/ionic telemetry off
- cordova/ionic build --no-telemetry

Answer (score 0):

I had a smiliar issue and fixed it by installing the latest JDK, make sure you have 64-bit and 32-bit versions installed (although I was on Windows for my sins).